# Erlang Crypto New API crypto_one_time/5 does not accept Options: [{encrypt,true}]

Tags: encryption, erlang, cryptoapi

Erlang Crypto new API does not work with `crypto_ops()`

Erts: 10.6.4

http://erlang.org/doc/apps/crypto/new_api.html#example-of-crypto_one_time-5

Example:

```
Key = <<1:128>>.
IV = <<0:128>>.
     
crypto:crypto_one_time(aes_128_ctr, Key, IV, <<"test">>,true).
```

Works as expected:

```
<<113,32,217,161>>
```

According to documentation:

```
FlagOrOptions = crypto_opts() | boolean()

crypto_opts() = boolean() | [crypto_opt()]
crypto_opt() = {encrypt, boolean()} | {padding, padding()}
```

"Selects encryption ({encrypt,true}) or decryption ({encrypt,false}) in the New API."

When I do:

```
Key = <<1:128>>.
IV = <<0:128>>.
crypto:crypto_one_time(aes_128_ctr, Key, IV, <<"test">>,[{encrypt,true}]).
```

I got error message:

```
* exception error: {badarg,{"api_ng.c",72},"Bad enc flag"}
 in function  crypto:ng_crypto_one_time_nif/5
    called as crypto:ng_crypto_one_time_nif(aes_128_ctr,
                                            <<0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1>>,
                                            <<0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0>>,
                                            <<"test">>,
                                            [{encrypt,true}])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some investigation of Erlang repository on github I see that the function `crypto:crypto_one_time/5` was changed for working with options, see [OTP-22.2.8](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/OTP-22.2.8/lib/crypto/src/crypto.erl#L1167) and for comparison please, see [OTP-23.0.3](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/OTP-23.0.3/lib/crypto/src/crypto.erl#L1438). Also if you take a look to the [crypto_init/3 function in OTP-22.2.8](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/OTP-22.2.8/lib/crypto/src/crypto.erl#L1068) and will try compare with [crypto_init/3 function in OTP-23.0.3](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/OTP-23.0.3/lib/crypto/src/crypto.erl#L1303) you will can see that the specification of variable and the name of variable was changed from `EncryptFlag :: boolean()` to `FlagOrOptions :: crypto_opts() | boolean()`. So, this is mean that looks like the pass of options like `[{encrypt, true/false}]` and `[{padding, true/false}]` wasn't implemented at all in `OTP-22.2.8` and for start using those options you need to upgrade Erlang till latest version.

Comment: The problem was not setting {encrypt,true} just instead of true.  I would like to pass padding options there. And this is not possible without writing [{encrypt,true},{padding,XXX}]

Comment: I see, so, for this case you need upgrade Erlang till latest version.

Comment: Not the best. Idea.  Too many places with  OTP 22 and Erts -10.6.4 :(

Comment: Yes, but as I understand that the options was added not in 22 release. 
`OTP-23.0.3` https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/OTP-23.0.3/lib/crypto/src/crypto.erl - spec `FlagOrOptions :: crypto_opts() | boolean()`. 
`OTP-22.2.8` https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/OTP-22.2.8/lib/crypto/src/crypto.erl - spec `EncryptFlag :: boolean()` in the same `crypto_init/3` function. So, this mean, the pass of options wasn't implemented at all in `Erts: 10.6.4`.

Comment: just upgraded to Erlang/OTP 23 [erts-11.0.3] . Works now. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the ERTS 10.6.4 has a bug in crypto_one_time implementation. I am running erts 11.0 and it works fine:

```erlang
alexei@MacBook-Pro src % erl                                                              
Erlang/OTP 23 [erts-11.0] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [ds:8:8:10] [async-threads:1] [hipe] [dtrace]

Eshell V11.0  (abort with ^G)

1> Key = <<1:128>>.
<<0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1>>
2> IV = <<0:128>>.
<<0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0>>
3> crypto:crypto_one_time(aes_128_ctr, Key, IV, <<"test">>,[{encrypt,true}]).
<<113,32,217,161>>
```

Just update Erlang version.